How do I use Cronicle map with openjdk 22?
I try to use it like this:
public class ChronicleMapBenchmark {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ChronicleMap<String, String> map = ChronicleMap
                .of(String.class, String.class)
                .name("benchmarkMap")
                .entries(1_000_000)
                .averageKeySize(10)
                .averageValueSize(20)
                .createPersistedTo(new File("chronicle-map.dat"));

        // Perform benchmark operations (e.g., put, get)
        for (int i = 0; i < 1_000_000; i++) {
            map.put("key" + i, "value" + i);
        }

        // Measure performance metrics

        map.close();
    }
}

pom.xml:
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>chronicle-repo</id>
        <url>https://nexus.chronicle.software/content/repositories/releases/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.openhft</groupId>
        <artifactId>chronicle-map</artifactId>
        <version>3.25ea6</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

I'm passsing these command line arguments:
--add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/com.sun.tools.javac.file=ALL-UNNAMED

Indeed I get this error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make public java.lang.Iterable com.sun.tools.javac.file.JavacFileManager.listLocationsForModules(javax.tools.JavaFileManager$Location) throws java.io.IOException accessible: module jdk.compiler does not "exports com.sun.tools.javac.file" to unnamed module @15bbf42f
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.invocationHelper(JavacTaskImpl.java:168)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall(JavacTaskImpl.java:100)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:94)
    at net.openhft.compiler.CachedCompiler.compileFromJava(CachedCompiler.java:119)
    at net.openhft.compiler.CachedCompiler.loadFromJava(CachedCompiler.java:158)
    at net.openhft.compiler.CachedCompiler.loadFromJava(CachedCompiler.java:85)
    at net.openhft.chronicle.values.ValueModel.createClass(ValueModel.java:326)
    at net.openhft.chronicle.values.ValueModel.createNativeClass(ValueModel.java:306)
    at net.openhft.chronicle.values.ValueModel.nativeClass(ValueModel.java:282)
    at net.openhft.chronicle.values.Values.nativeClassFor(Values.java:89)
    at net.openhft.chronicle.map.ChronicleMapBuilder.createWithFile(ChronicleMapBuilder.java:1695)
    at net.openhft.chronicle.map.ChronicleMapBuilder.createPersistedTo(ChronicleMapBuilder.java:1588)
    at ChronicleMapBenchmark.main(ChronicleMapBenchmark.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make public java.lang.Iterable com.sun.tools.javac.file.JavacFileManager.listLocationsForModules(javax.tools.JavaFileManager$Location) throws java.io.IOException accessible: module jdk.compiler does not "exports com.sun.tools.javac.file" to unnamed module @15bbf42f
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.throwInaccessibleObjectException(AccessibleObject.java:388)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:364)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:312)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:203)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:197)
    at net.openhft.compiler.MyJavaFileManager.invokeNamedMethodIfAvailable(MyJavaFileManager.java:214)
    at net.openhft.compiler.MyJavaFileManager.listLocationsForModules(MyJavaFileManager.java:77)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.ClientCodeWrapper$WrappedJavaFileManager.listLocationsForModules(ClientCodeWrapper.java:410)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.ModuleFinder$ModuleLocationIterator.hasNext(ModuleFinder.java:139)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.ModuleFinder.scanModulePath(ModuleFinder.java:295)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.ModuleFinder.findAllModules(ModuleFinder.java:188)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Modules.getUnnamedModuleCompleter(Modules.java:1458)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Modules.setCompilationUnitModules(Modules.java:477)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Modules.enter(Modules.java:271)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Modules.initModules(Modules.java:237)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.initModules(JavaCompiler.java:1058)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:949)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.lambda$doCall$0(JavacTaskImpl.java:104)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.invocationHelper(JavacTaskImpl.java:152)
    ... 12 more

How do I fix it?

my java exe path is: .jdks\openjdk-22.0.1\bin\java.exe

'jdk.compiler does not "exports com.sun.tools.javac.file"' from the error message suggests the need of using an additional --add-exports option

@user85421 what should the extra flag look like?

see java tool documentation (I don't really know, I would need to check the documentation to answer that)

@StepanYakovenko should be something like --add-exports jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file=ALL-UNNAMED

I found full list of options here:
https://chronicle.software/chronicle-support-java-17/
--add-exports=java.base/jdk.internal.ref=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-exports=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-exports=jdk.unsupported/sun.misc=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED

